# How to get a column creation script workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I upload my sql database on workbench to add properly a new relation between two tables. But I only need The `ALTER TABLE .. ADD .. AFTER` script not the `CREATE TABLE` because it's already created with inserted values.

So is there any solution to get the script only to create the column with its foreign keys ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when this function was introduced, but with workbench 5.2.33 you can obtaing the ALTER statment by selecting the table you want to alter, and right-click and select ALTER

[image]

After this you can define the Foreing Keys

[image]

And when you press "Apply", you can see and copy the script

[image]

Once you have the script, click "cancel" and don't apply the changes.

Comment: Sorry  @KeizerBridge i'm not familiarized with workbench for mac. Maybe some other user can help you. Any way you can always create the statement by your self